# How did the Predator use its cloaking device after short-circuiting in the water?

Tags: plot-explanation, predator

In *Predator* (1987) when the Predator walks through the water the cloaking device shorted and the Predator appears in front of Dutch.

Before the last battle between Dutch and the Predator we can see the Predator using his cloaking device again to become invisible.

How did the Predator fix his cloaking device?

Comment: Predators are smart and tech-savvy.  Maybe he just fixed it after it dried out?

Comment: maybe it was only the*active field* that shorted out, and the device was fine once it dried off.  Like overloading a fuse and the switch automatically shuts off.  All you have to do is go flip the switch to turn it on again, once it's safe to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It didn't need fixing.

His cloaking device was never damaged, it simply was not able to cloak in the water. The cloaking field is not able to operate in water, so that is why is shorted out. The effect is not terminal and once the Yautja (the Predator) exits the water, the cloaking field can be restored within seconds. The only exception to this is if the cloaking device is physically damaged, but that has nothing to with the water.